# How to access Wordpress' global $wpdb from PHP?

Tags: wordpress, global

I'm trying to execute a query in PHP against a MySQL database. My code is below:

```
<?php
require_once ("wp-includes/wp-db.php");
global $wpdb;
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM wp_db_posts" );
echo $myrows;
?>
```

After executing this code, I get a `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on null in C:\Apache24\htdocs\wordpress\me.php on line 4`

I'm actually new to WordPress and want to know exactly how can I access the $wpdb global variable from PHP. My databses are pre-fixed with wp_db_.

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 5):

assuming you script placed in the root directory of WordPress you should load wordpress not access the wp-db.php directly so your code should be like this:

```
  <?php
  require_once "wp-load.php";
  global $wpdb;
 $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts" );
```

and you can't echo myrows as you will get object not string you should use instead

```
  var_dump()  or print_r()
```

Comment: I made a mistake...I'll try again!

Comment: did you get the result that you are looking for?

Comment: you have an issue with your query as well i change the query code check it now please

Comment: I'm getting Array() as the result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Now it works! Thanks for all your help.  I'm new to Wordpress and PHP. Thanks again!

Comment: You are most welcome if you like my answer please accept it :)